# Get Cognito username in AWS Amplify ExpressJS Lambda

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an ExpressJS Lambda created and integrated with API Gateway automatically through the Amplify CLI. When a user makes a request, how could I get the Cognito username inside the Lambda? An old Github thread pointed towards custom authorizers, but I'm hoping there's an easier solution out there now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())

app.get('/project', function (req, res) {
    res.json({success: `Welcome ${cognitoUsername}`, url: req.url});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a straightforward solution after a day of struggling.

Works by matching the identity token in the request with the corresponding Cognito pool user with the same sub.

Retrieve the user:

```js
async function getUser(req) {
    const IDP_REGEX = /.*\/.*,(.*)\/(.*):CognitoSignIn:(.*)/;
    const authProvider = req.apiGateway.event.requestContext.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider;
    const [, , , userId] = authProvider.match(IDP_REGEX);

    const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    const listUsersResponse = await cognito
        .listUsers({
            UserPoolId: process.env.AUTH_ENDASHBOARD0613289A_USERPOOLID,
            Filter: `sub = "${userId}"`,
            Limit: 1,
        })
        .promise();
    return listUsersResponse.Users[0];
}
```

Extract the email from the attributes:

```js
function getEmail(user) {
    const emailAttribute = user.Attributes.find(attr => attr.Name === "email");
    return emailAttribute ? emailAttribute.Value : null;
}
```

Full usage:

```js
app.get('/project', async function(req, res) {
    try {
        const user = await getUser(req)
        const email = getEmail(user)

        res.json({ user, message: `Success! Email: ${email}`, url: req.url });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.json({ error, message: `Failed :(` });
    }
});
```